# NavigationLink takes me to the parent view of the view with the navigation stack on it

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I am new to SwiftUI and I am simply experimenting with different NavigationStack options. I have a navigation stack that shows a list of words. When the user clicks on the navigation link it shows a detailed view of that word. Very simple.

The code below doesn't work. When I click on the link, it takes me to the a screen which just flashes and it goes directly to the parent view of the view below.

```
var body: some View {     
        NavigationStack {
            List(dictionary, id: \.id) { wordDefinition in
                NavigationLink(wordDefinition.g_keyword, value: wordDefinition)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: DictionaryEntry.self) { wordDefinition in
                DefinitionCardView(wordDefinition: wordDefinition)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
```

This code works fine.

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(dictionary, id: \.id) { wordDefinition in
                NavigationLink(wordDefinition.g_keyword, destination: DefinitionCardView(wordDefinition: wordDefinition))
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
```

Parent view of the above code. I am just playing around with code so please ignore any logic or optimization issues. For example SomeViewThatActuallyDoesNothing() acts like a button that if pressed, takes you to the view in question. But that's just me trying different things and I don't consider this a good design choice. However, this illogical design choice presents the problem I am facing here and curiosity got me. Why does one version work and the other doesn't?

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                
                SomeViewThatActuallyDoesNothing(searchWord: $searchWord)
                .onTapGesture {
                    isSearchFieldTapped = true;
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    DefinitionCardView(wordDefinition: wordOfTheDay)
                } label: {
                    SomeSampleCardView(wordOfTheDay: wordOfTheDay)
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isSearchFieldTapped) {
                MainSearchView() // This is the view with the problem (the code above)
            }
            
        }
```

I am curios now why the first version is not working while the second is fine.

EDIT:
Minimal Reproducible Example

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink {
                    MinNOTWorkingListView()
                } label: {
                    Text("A View With a Problem")
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    MinWorkingListView()
                } label: {
                    Text("A Working View")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                NavigationLink {
                    MinCardView(wordDef: "wordOfTheDay")
                } label: {
                    Text("Some Text")
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}



struct MinWorkingListView: View {
    
    private var wordList: [String] = {
        var list: [String] = []
        for i in 1...5 {
            list.append("Word" + String(i))
        }
        return list
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(wordList, id: \.self) { wordDefinition in
                NavigationLink(wordDefinition, destination: MinCardView(wordDef: wordDefinition))
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct MinNOTWorkingListView: View {
    
    private var wordList: [String] = {
        var list: [String] = []
        for i in 1...5 {
            list.append("Word" + String(i))
        }
        return list
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(wordList, id: \.self) { wordDefinition in
                NavigationLink(wordDefinition, value: wordDefinition)
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { wordDefinition in
                MinCardView(wordDef: wordDefinition)
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        }
    }
}

struct MinCardView: View {    
    var wordDef: String
    var body: some View {
            Text(wordDef)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are nesting `NavigationStack`s? You should not do that. Just use one `NavigationStack`. Anyway, please show a [mcve].

Comment: show the code for the views, not just some bits of the body. Show how you call these view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like mentioned in a comment by @Sweeper, you should not nest two `NavigationStack`s.

Another thing, when mixing `NavigationLink(destination:label:)` with `NavigationLink(value:label:)` like that:

```
struct ContView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: {
                NavigationLink(value: "Value") {
                    Text("To SomeView")
                }
            }){
                Text("Start")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
                SomeView(value: value)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

..it seems to overwhelm the `NavigationStack` (..and it might actually be a bug).

**Solution**:

You can use several `NavigationLink(value:label:)`s with dedicated `.navigationDestination(for:destination)` modifiers for each.

Alternatively you could introduce a new `Destination` enum and handle its value in a `.navigationDestination(for:destination)` with a `switch` statement:

```
enum Destination: Hashable {
    case list
    case card(String)
}

struct ContView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            NavigationLink(value: Destination.list) {
                Text("List")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                switch destination {
                case .list:
                    ListView()
                case .card(let wordDefinition):
                    SomeView(value: wordDefinition)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

struct ListView: View {

    private var wordList: [String] = {
        var list: [String] = []
        for i in 1...5 {
            list.append("Word" + String(i))
        }
        return list
    }()

    var body: some View {
            List(wordList, id: \.self) { wordDefinition in
                NavigationLink(wordDefinition, value: Destination.card(wordDefinition))
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is not mentioned anywhere (at least that I could see) that NavigationStack should not be nested but this seems to be the answer.